# Error Undefined index al utilizar ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy tratando de pasar una valor por de `ajax` a un formulario `PHP`, pero me dice que tengo un error:

> Undefined index.

el código que llama a la función `PHP` es el siguiente:

```html
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="ID_Nova" id="ID_Nova" placeholder="Número de documento" required="true" value ="<?php echo $ID_Novedad ?>" readonly ></td>
<body onload="lista_DescuentoNovedad(ID_Nova.value);">
```

La función de `ajax` es la siguiente:

```html
 function lista_DescuentoNovedad(ID_Novedad){
    $(document).ready(function() {
  /*var ID_Novedad = $('#ID_Nova').val();*/
  var datastring ='ID_Novedad=' + ID_Novedad;
          $.ajax({
          beforeSend: function(){
             $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html('<b>Actualizando lista de Descuentos en la novedad...</b>');
           },
          url: 'lista_DescuentoNovedad.php',
    data: datastring,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(x){
            $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html(x);
   /********************HAY QUE VALIDAR #lista_clientes*******************************/
            $("#lista_clientes").dataTable();
           },
           error: function(jqXHR,estado,error){}
           });
          });
 }
```

El código `PHP` donde recibe la información es el siguiente:

```html
include ("funciones/conex.php");
$link=Conectarse();

$ID_Novedad = $_POST['ID_Novedad'];
$AnoActual=date("Y");
$con=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_dtldcto where ID_Novedad=$ID_Novedad AND Estado = 'PENDIENTE'",$link);
```

Comment: Agrega el error que te sale, el undefined index se da porque no has definido una variable bien y las estás llamando

Comment: El error es el siguiente "Undefined index: ID_Novedad"

Comment: `/*var ID_Novedad = $('#ID_Nova').val();*/` ¿Por qué lo tienes comentado?

Comment: Era una prueba que estaba haciendo, es que he intentado varias cosas, pero ninguna me ha resultado hasta el momento, esa prueba era llamar la función sin enviar ningún parámetro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo que me comentas el error que te da es porque no estás definiendo la variable `ID_Novedad` la razón por la cual se genera el error es que en el archivo `php` estás definiendo `$ID_Novedad = $_POST['ID_Novedad'];`, pero en el `Ajax` lo tienes comentado `/*var ID_Novedad = $('#ID_Nova').val();*/` por lo tanto lo único que debes hacer es quitarlo como comentario y mandarlo, una manera puede ser así

```
var ID_Novedad = $('#ID_Nova').val();
var datos = {
            'ID_Novedad': ID_Novedad
        };
```

Quedaría más o menos así:

```
 function lista_DescuentoNovedad(ID_Novedad){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ID_Novedad = $('#ID_Nova').val();
        var datos = {
            'ID_Novedad': ID_Novedad
        };  
          $.ajax({
          beforeSend: function(){
             $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html('<b>Actualizando lista de Descuentos en la novedad...</b>');
           },
          url: 'lista_DescuentoNovedad.php',
          data: datos,//Pones la variable datos que es donde se guardan todos los datos que se van a mandar por post
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(x){
            $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html(x);
            /********************HAY QUE VALIDAR #lista_clientes*******************************/
            $("#lista_clientes").dataTable();
           },
           error: function(jqXHR,estado,error){}
           });
          });
 }
```

Ojala te sirva, saludos!!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, la solución fue precisa,de nuevo, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Me alegra mucho que te haya servido, recuerda puntuar positivamente y marcar la respuesta como correcta, suerte con tu proyecto, saludos!!

Comment: Hola DaxTter, que pena molestarte, envíe más de un dato y me genera el mismo error con los demás datos enviados.

Comment: Depronto es porque lo mandas como datastring, mandalo como te mostré `var data = { ID_Novedad : valor, otravariable : valor};` me cuentas a ver, la cuestión es que así se vuelve un objeto json, y cómo lo mandas sería como se mandaría en una petición de tipo get, en el post funciona parecido, pero no sé bien como, así que, aprovecha el hecho de que el mismo lo construye y mándalo así

Comment: Recuerda que no debes añadir cosas a tu pregunta cómo una respuesta, en vez de eso, edita la pregunta